# How to control chunking of shared code using `import()` chunks (Webpack 2.2)

Tags: webpack

Using `webpack` version `2.2.0`.

I have a single page app with a single `entry` config: `entry: { app: ['./js/main.js'] }`. This is an application which dynamically loads views via `import('./js/views/1')` for code splitting.

The issue I'm having is that the generated `views/1`, `views/2`, etc.. files that get created have a ton of duplicated modules inside of them. The files and their contents look like this:

- main: `./js/main.js`

  - 0: `./js/views/1.js`
  - `./js/modules/a.js`
  - `./js/modules/b.js`
  - 1:`./js/views/2.js`
  - `./js/modules/b.js`
  - `./js/modules/c.js`

Note that both `views/1.js` and `views/2.js` have a full copy of shared `modules/b.js` module. In my case I have dozens of views and many more shared modules so the duplication is a huge concern for me. Here is what the `webpack-bundle-analyzer' looks like:

[image: Bundle Analyzer]

I've tried adding the `CommonChunkPlugin` to help address this, but it doesn't seem to affect the dynamic imports at all.

What I'm looking for is a way for webpack to automatically move all shared modules into separate files. Ideally, I'd want webpack to output the following chunks:

- main: `./js/main.js`

  - 0: `./js/views/1.js`
  - 1: `./js/views/2.js`
  - 2: `./js/modules/a.js`
  - 3: `./js/modules/b.js`
  - 4: `./js/modules/c.js`

So each module is literally a separate chunk. This would be the most optimal way to load them using HTTP2.

Here is the code for the sample project: https://github.com/EvNaverniouk/webpack-code-splitting

How can I achieve this?

I believe this is related to this issue: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3981

Comment: I think I'm seeing the same issue you have [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44532817/property-code-splitting-modules-that-import-third-party-libraries)

Comment: @evgueni-naverniouk Were you able to ever figure this out?

Comment: @KFE Nope. webpack 4 does more aggressive chunking by default, so that helped a bit, but I still haven't found a way to get it to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the duplication error, you can use the CommonsChunkPlugin provided by the webpack optimization package. Stated by the [documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin), it does the following:

> Generate an extra chunk, which contains common modules shared between entry points.

As for the second problem you're describing, that would be a task for gulp. Gulp takes an input stream and outputs that stream into a file. Basically creating a 1-by-1 copy of the original filed, but then transpiled, compiled, etcetera.

I wouldn't recommend the second structure for the web, since it creates so many HTTP requests for the browser which can take quite some time. Especially if you're website is running on the HTTP/1.1 protocol. It's usually more beneficial to let the client download less files with more content in them.

Comment: I've tried using the CommonsChunkPlugin but it doesn't seem to apply to any `import()` statement inside the main entry point. The plugin seems to only be able to create common chunks from 2 or more entry points, not from the child imports of a single import. I've tried all sorts of configurations for the plugin, but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Could you share your configuration?

Comment: I've updated the original question with more details. And here is the repo to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/EvNaverniouk/webpack-code-splitting

Answer (score 0):

In webpack 4, I think what you are looking for is to set the minSize to 0. Webpack will duplicate this code if it thinks it will save an HTTP request. Setting minsize to 0 forces it to separate.

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        chunks: "all",
        minSize: 0
    }
}
```